# Easy way to see if an input is an integer?

Tags: java, input, validation

Is there a simple way to see if an input is an integer in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {
  Integer.parseInt(myString);
} catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  // Not an integer
}
```

[Documentation for `parseInt()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) if you're interested.